# Google Calendar insert events into custom calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get campus talk info and insert into Google calendar.

My question is, I can only insert the event to default calendar(xxxx@gmail.com) but can not insert the event into other calendar( for example, the calendar named "campus talk")

I'm using python to do this, and I'm using the Google calendar api v2.

Here is the code.

calendarExample class is [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/calendar/calendarExample.py).

```
email = raw_input("Email:")
password = raw_input("Password:")
infolist = CampusTalk("http://my.yingjiesheng.com/xuanjianghui_school_4.html")
calendar = calendarExample.CalendarExample(email,password)
# Delete old calendar
feed = calendar.cal_client.GetOwnCalendarsFeed()
for entry in feed.entry:
    if entry.title.text == "Campus Talk":
        print 'Deleting calendar: %s' % entry.title.text
        calendar.cal_client.Delete(entry.GetEditLink().href)
# Insert new calendar
calendar._InsertCalendar(title="Campus Talk",description="Calendar of Campus Talk",time_zone='Asia/Shanghai', hidden=False, location='Shanghai',color='#2952A3')

for campustalk_info in infolist:
    try:
        content = "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s"%(campustalk_info["city"],campustalk_info["school"],campustalk_info["location"],campustalk_info["time"].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),campustalk_info["link"])
        if campustalk_info["time"] == "0":
            campustalk_info["time"] = campustalk_info["date"]
        start_time = (campustalk_info["time"]+datetime.timedelta(hours=-8)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
        end_time = (campustalk_info["time"]+datetime.timedelta(hours=-6)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
        calendar._InsertSingleEvent(title=campustalk_info["company"], content=content, where=campustalk_info["location"], start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time)
    except Exception,e:
        print e
print "Finished!"
```

As you can see, I create a new calendar "Campus Talk", how can I insert events into this calendar instead of the default one?

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Did you see my answer? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`_InsertCalendar` returns a `Calendar` object (see line `157`). Use that one, instead of your current `calendar` object when you call `_InsertSingleEvent` (as in line `557`).

---

For **example** note the creation and use of the `talks` obect:

```
talks = calendar._InsertCalendar(title="Campus Talk", ... ,color='#2952A3')

....

talks._InsertSingleEvent(title=campustalk_info["company"], ... ,end_time=end_time)
```

(**Note** that I have abbreviated the long lines with `...`)

Comment: Oh, I see! Let me have a try. I'm sorry I have not checked my inbox for a long time.

Comment: Hi Geoff, I have tested your code. I'm sorry to tell you that I failed. I remembered I have tried this before, it will return errors "'CalendarEntry' object has no attribute '_InsertSingleEvent'", I have no idea about this, could you help me ?